# Get data for JSON file PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

This may seem like a duplicate question, but my JSON is formatted differently than other examples I have seen. The which I am using:

```
$str = file_get_contents($tmp);
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$project_id = $json["project_id"];
```

My JSON is formatted like:

```
[{"project_id": 2.0, "name": "Anna", "place": "Amsterdam", "date": "31 October 2016"}]
```

The error which I am getting:

```
Undefined index: project_id
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: `$project_id = $json[0]["project_id"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (note the `[0]`):

```
$project_id = $json[0]["project_id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing one level

```
$str = file_get_contents($tmp);
$json = json_decode($str, true);
foreach($json as $j){
 echo $j['project_id'];
}
```

Your response datas is an Array of jsons object so have to loop on it.

Also, if you want bypass loop and get directly first result you can do this :

```
$str = file_get_contents($tmp);    
$json = current(json_decode($str, true));
$project_id = $json["project_id"];
```